# CSS Ignore Parent Container for Always at Bottom Footer Template

Tags: css

I'm trying to use an always at bottom footer like the one in this tutorial:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Basically the div structure is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

This works just fine until a design-required parent div wraps this entire structure like this:

```
<div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContainerPanel" style="display: block;">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find a solution that keeps the footer at the bottom when the text does not extend past the viewport as well as appears after the body div when the text is long enough to push the footer down past the bottom of the viewport.

Thanks in advance for your CSS insight!

Comment: Give your outer element a `min-height` of `100%`. That should allow your inner elements to follow the original intended layout. Otherwise, I'de suggest using a block above the footer and the footer separately, giving the block above the footer a `min-height` of `calc(100% = footerheight)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% height to parent container will work.

```
<div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContainerPanel" style="display: block;height:100%">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3cg81u1u/

Comment: That did the trick!  Your fast response is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative` from `#container` and add it instead to `.RadAjaxPanel`